# Places with car roads turned into bike roads

Tags: traffic

What can we do to minimize car usage and petroleum and other car energy consumption? I was thinking designating some car lanes as bike-only lanes could work in some places, or even having an hour where only bike traffic is agreed or something like that.

Bikes could have special carts attached to them for transporting whatever messed to be transported during those hours, and some special vehicles would be nevertheless authorized.

How would this work? Where has a similar system been implemented, and what are the details?

Comment: Lead by example - just ride your bike.

Answer (score 2):

In my city, they shut down [the parkway](http://www.ncc-ccn.gc.ca/places-to-visit/parks-paths/things-to-do/nokia-sunday-bikedays) and the roads in the provincial park on Sunday mornings during the summer for bicycle traffic only. Its a great way to get people out on their bikes when they aren't comfortable in traffic. It also helps relieve congestion on the shared bike/walk paths that would be just swarmed with riders in these areas if they didn't close the roads. The roads aren't really that busy outside of weekday rush hour traffic anyway.

Comment: What stops cars driving in anyway?   Are there physical barriers?

Comment: There are barriers, and it's completely closed to cars.

Answer (score 0):

In Christchurch, New Zealand we've had the Lyttelton Road Tunnel closed twice in my memory for pedestrians and riders.

Normally its a dedicated road tunnel for cars / trucks / busses.

In 1993 and 2014 it was closed for a morning and many thousands of people got the chance to walk through and back.

It was a huge success in getting people out, but so many people you couldn't ride through.  Even walking was slow.

Plus there was a lot of anger in the car drivers who had to take alternate roads up and over or around the hills.